# How do I autorun my Python script when I plug in my USB device?

Tags: windows, windows-10, autorun

I want to execute my Python script (at root, "autorun.pyw") whenever my USB device is plugged into a port.
I don't want to install any software. I am using Windows 10, and I have tried using an autorun.inf file.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. First Step: Install software

Restore the auto-run function To restore the "auto-run" function, the first thing we will need to do is download APO USB Autorun, a small free program that monitors the USB devices connected to the computer. Once installed, whenever you connect a USB storage device, such as a USB stick, it will check if there is an autorun.inf file inside the device and will run the configured program.

2. Second Step: Create autorun.inf

Create the autorun.inf file To automatically run a program from the flash drive, it needs to have two things, the program you want to run automatically and a script file that points to the program on the flash drive. Copy the executable file of the program you want to run to the pendrive. Then open the notepad, copy the text below and paste it into the notepad window to create the autorun script. [autorun]; Open = MEUAPP.exe ShellExecute = MEUAPP.exe UseAutoPlay = 1 Once you have pasted the text in the notepad, replace the text “MEUAPP” with the name of the program file you copied to the USB stick that will run automatically, as shown in the example below. Then, save the file to the USB stick named autorun.inf. Important: Make sure to select the option “All files (*. *)” In the “Type” field so that the file is saved with an INF extension and not a TXT extension. The flash drive should now contain the program's executable file and the autorun.inf file you just created. You can use the USB stick to place other files, but be sure to keep both files. Note: If the portable program has multiple files, you can copy its folder to the USB stick, just make sure to enter the path in the ShellExecute field. Ex: ShellExecute = PASTADOAPP \ MEUAPP.exe.

3. Final Step: Configure and run automatically

Run the program automatically: Once this is done, whenever you connect the pendrive to the computer, APO USB Autorun will detect your autorun.inf file inside the pendrive and will automatically run the program you have configured. Finally, note that you will need to install APO USB Autorun on all computers where you want to use autorun. Still, it can still be useful if you work on the same computers.

Comment: *Without* installing software

Comment: No, you have to install the APO USB Autorun software on the machine you want to use autorun.inf.